# How do people study analysis? Specifically, how can I build connections between different topics faster or before I do the exercise?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, analysis, education, advice

I asked my question in another branch of stackexchange (https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/158563/what-can-i-do-with-my-failing-analysis-class-failing-graduate-study), and the people there referred me to this site. I extracted the part more relevant to math here, but I would really appreciate it if you can help me with the bigger question about my graduate school plan and options listed in the other link.

I am a first-year master's student in a math graduate program. Out of the four classes I am taking at the moment, I think I might be failing my analysis class.

Precisely speaking, the letter grade won't come out until Xmas, so it's not the final result yet. I still have another exam about one month later, which I THEORETICALLY can max out and get 100% on it - this might flip the situation putting me at somewhere around A- or even an A, but I'm not optimistic about this.

66.6% of the course has passed, and in the first 2 exams I got a below-average score and another lowest-in-the-class score. I am not sure what's precisely a fail in this class because my professor said he hasn't drawn the lines, nor looked into any grade stats of the class by far. However, I don't see a good chance to get an A from this class - I might get a B or somewhere around/below this level.

I have never been a big fan of analysis ever. I very much enjoyed algebra and want to apply for a PhD and do some research in it. Yet this probably upcoming fail will put me at a significant disadvantage in the application: I will apply to some PhD programs next year. This means I only have a graduate-level transcript of 2 semesters (including this one that I am having trouble with) to present to the admission committee. Having anything around or below a B might as well just block me from going anywhere, even though I am not sure about the validity of this idea either.

I read the textbook, read the notes, watched all lectures, and finished my homework very carefully. I asked my TA for office hour appointment every single week to ask him questions and go over my write-ups, to an extent I think I might be taking too much time from him. I also checked with my professor to confirm if there is any more things that I can do. He thought there is no problem with my strategy, but he confirmed my awkward situation where I have correct intuition for every problem, but I can't seal up the proof nicely. He went over the rubric for me, and very often I didn't realize some of the items require a proof. He doesn't seem to know how to deal with my situation either except assigning me a bad letter score in the end. On the other hand, this is a graduate-level class where no solutions to HW are posted at all - so even if I have a chance to confirm with my TA on 1 or 2 HWQs, there is no way for me to know whether I am proving every single thing as nicely as expected BEFORE the exams make punishment on me. (Or is there a hidden way to know how well my proofs are that everybody knows except me? If there is, please comment below. Please...)

I would really appreciate any suggestions on how to study analysis because I always get panic in an analysis exam. I immediately get panic whenever I find the exercises behind the book to be very different from what appears on the exam, and they always are. Sometimes even understanding a theorem is not easy to me. After I finally understood them, I am still unable to quickly make connections between the theorem that I just learned and the ones I learned 2 months ago, UNLESS I have seen some exercises around their connections before the exam, which never happened actually.

I usually would just suck it up all by myself when I was in undergrad, but now since I'm in a master's program which is significantly shorter than any undergrad program, I am very concerned about what this indicates or where this will put me at. Analysis always makes me feel like I am inferior, and the study strategies I have always been using are not working at all. No matter how hard I try and how much time I am spending on it, I'm just not getting ahead of the class. I always feel gaps between my knowledge system that hold me from excelling in an analysis class, but I don't exactly know how to fill these gaps. I would LOVE to find a way to master analysis, but I just don't know how after I have tried going over the proofs in the class, understanding the theorems, etc. From next week we are going into a new chapter that is not cumulative upon the previous material which I am uncomfortable with, so this literally is my last chance if I want to flip my situation in this class. Any suggestions for studying analysis, please...?

Comment: Can you provide an example of topics in analysis that you are having trouble with?

Comment: "he confirmed my awkward situation where I have correct intuition for every problem, but I can't seal up the proof nicely" That seems like the key issue to me. I'd be curious to see some examples of this. If your proof or argument that you have written doesn't make sense, you should be able to tell that it doesn't make sense. When this happens, are you aware at the time that your proof is not correct? Or does it seem to you that you have a correct proof, only to find later that it has been judged to be incorrect.

Comment: Most of the similar cases I found are due to the math learners are not able to build a sense of rigour through their undergraduate years. ( Mostly because undergraduate teachers are really lenient on students mistakes). So without more info on your case, and based on your goal to have a Phd, I would advise you, for now, to lower your speed,  remove some courses to have time to work on each theorem, lemma,etc; and have someone to bash you each time your argument lack of rigour.

Comment: @T.H.Shehadi, thank you for your reply! I don't think it's with a specific topic; since I started taking real analysis from undergrad to now when I just finished the grad complex analysis, I am having this general trouble. I only realized this after this failing second exam in grad cplx anlss - one thing I was asked is to prove a function is entire. I claimed that it was a product of entire functions, while professor expected more along the lines about "locally unif convergent." I knew this condition, but I failed to identify that I was expected to go this way. {see below for char lim}

Comment: @little, thank you for your reply! Sometimes I can get slight feeling that my proof looks different from what a professor would write, but I couldn't identify where the lack lies. Sometimes I don't know that it was wrong at all until someone on a higher level tells me that. In this last exam, I created a contradiction by saying e^{z}(e^{(a-1)z}-1)-P(z) [P is plnml] is not a polynomial while equal to a plnml, which means the equation is wrong. I didn't know I was expected to prove e^{z}(e^{(a-1)z}-1)-P(z) is not a plnml at all. I thought this was from eyeballing until I got points deducted.

Comment: @ParesseuxNguyen, TY for your advice! I will definitely take some courses off next semester. In UG I did take some very rgrs real anlss, and they already appeared to me very hard to quickly build connections btwn ideas. Often I tried to make my proof more rgrs in one exrcs, but then in the next exrcs, it required using a different thm with another(hard to think) start. Then I spent much time figuring out why and how I could come up with that genius proof by myself. I got a sense of rigor from that class, but didn't get how to cnct dfrt ideas/chptr, and don't know how to see sth being not rgrs.

Comment: Dear wtrskalagla, To be honest, I identify myself as a slower learner. I often spent a lot of time to understand a new mathematical object ( and sometimes it takes days to just get a grasp of a paragraph). So if you are looking for a quick learning methodology, I think I'm not of great help to you. On contrary, as a slow learner, I can tell you one secret ( I don't know if someone has told you yet), most of tools and arguments, which you need to understand your courses, are always lied in the proof of lemmas and theorems in your course. So most of the times,

Comment: if you are able to reproduce most of theorems and examples in your lecture notes, you can quickly and easily get a grasp of most of your exercises. This is the farthest I can safely say. More things are needed to pay attention, depending on each case.

Comment: @T.H.Shehadi Another example where I felt difficult to make connections is to (first judge whether there exists one and then) prove there is no conformal mapping from unit disk to entire complex plane. The solution invoked liouville where an entire bdd function must be a constant. I knew this theorem but couldn't think of using this actively on my own if there isn't one giving me a hint towards this direction. I just got an intuition that there must not exist one, but I immediately get lost when finding a tool to start the proof.

Comment: @ParesseuxNguyen, TY for the reply! Yes this is what I've been doing (reproducing the proof) b/c I often feel I have very limited resources besides doing this. I usually make a lot of time to digest information in a chapter. However,  drawing lines between information from different chapters is still difficult to me when such connections are only requested in an exam and had not appeared anywhere in the lect/txtbk proof or exercises/hw. This problem is particularly clear when I am looking at new problems from analysis, and barely there from other areas. Do you have any suggestions about this?

Comment: "Or is there a hidden way to know how well my proofs are that everybody knows except me?" You could post a question on a site like Math StackExchange asking for [proof-verification]. "not appeared anywhere in the lect/txtbk proof or exercises/hw." Then get other sources of problems like other textbooks. "I didn't realize some of the items require a proof" err on the side of proving more claims, and maybe get a tutor to help. "knew this theorem but couldn't think of using this" It sounds like you don't have a systematic approach to proofs. E.g. 1. List every theorem mentioning "conformal". 2...

Comment: "Or is there a hidden way to know how well my proofs are that everybody knows except me?" The other side of this is that, at least by the level of a PhD student, you should ideally be comfortable enough with rigor to largely be able to check your own work/be able to expand an argument until it is basically fully rigorous for a person outside of logic class. If you're surprised by deductions the professor is showing, you may want to find a teacher/tutor to help you develop this skill separately. With that core math skill solid, you'd just need to practice applying real analysis theorems, etc.